# Error in installing drivers using Python

Tags: python, runtime-error

I have to install some device driver using Python. I am getting error as

> [Windows Error 5]:Access is denied

```
install=subprocess.Popen(path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
install.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have permissions to tun the file at the specified path. Try running this as an administrator.